# Editing “MediaWiki:Vector.css” of my MediaWiki

Tags: css, mediawiki

I want to install [Skin:Vector-DarkCSS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Vector-DarkCSS) on my `MediaWiki`. It must be simple, but second step of installation instructions syas I have to edit `MediaWiki:Vector.css` on my wiki. I searched for file with name `MediaWiki:Vector.css`, but could not found in `MediaWiki` home. Where is that file? Do I need to create that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaWiki:Vector.css is not a file on your filessytem. Its "just" a Wikipage. Just type "MediaWiki:Vector.css" in the searchbar and create this Wikipage.

After this MediaWiki:Vector.css will be embedded in your css.